# Using .AddItem With Different Comboboxes in Excel VBA Userform

Tags: vba, for-loop, foreach, combobox, userform

I have a userform with a lot of comboboxes. I am trying to use .AddItem when the userform is intialized, with no success.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Sub Userform_Initialize()
  Dim cCont As MSForms.ComboBox

  For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    cCont.AddItem "Item Added"
  Next cCont
End Sub
```

I usually get a runtime error 13 "type mismatch" come up. Not sure if that has anything to do with the button I have on the userform as well.

How do I loop through a userform and use `.AddItem` to each combobox? Once I get the code on how to do this, I'll wrap it in an `If` statement to only add it to certain comboboxes with certain words in the name, if that helps for context.

Thanks in advance,

-Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony,

You are trying to call the [AddItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835377.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method on each control on the form. But not all controls provide the AddItem method. You need to check out whether a particular control is combobox or not. And only if the control is combobox you may call the AddItem method.

> How do I loop through a userform and use .AddItem to each combobox?

It is not clear where you need to loop through. Could you be more specific?

Comment: "But not all controls provide the AddItem method" is what made me look into using an if statement to check the type of control. Once I wrapped cCont.AddItem "text" into the if statement, it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add controls to a userform that I have found is to follow this procedure.

```
Dim NewComboBox as Control
Set NewComboBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    With NewComboBox
        'Inside of this part you can put .name or any other property in the
        'activex controls properties part, .left .top .width and .height determine the size of the box
        .Name = Whatever Name You Desire
    End With
```

Put this in your userform_initialize() event and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me adding two combo boxes to a userform. Only thing I can think of is the correct references are not enabled for some reason.